# why "SPUserCodeV4" service stop automatically

Tags: web-services, error, central-administration, sharepoint-server, server-farm

Whenever I make "SPUserCodeV4" starting using service.msc , it stops automatically.
Do you have any idea about whyit behaves this way?

And even if it is shown on the 
Central Administration -> System Settings -> Manage services on server-> “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation User Code Service” is started I found "SPUserCodeV4" in service.msc as stopped

Also alot of times I face that "Manage services on server" is disappeared and I can't see it at allso what is the reason for this ?

I'm using win7 and sp2010

Comment: Well regarding why you can not see Manage services on server, you need to run IE as Administrator or use the Central Administration shortcut for this node to be visible

Comment: Did you try to run the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation User Code Service" with an account which has Farm Administration Privileges?

Comment: @RobertLindgren when using ie as administrators it is shown but if i made that with firefox it asked me for pass then the problem not solved in firefox , so how can i know what is the credintial used in ie to use it on firefox although im not having any pass except the one windows pass i use when i loging

Comment: @VardhamanDeshpande i think i have only one account on my windows7 which i login with and this what i used in running it